# Qt QTreeView: Only allow to drop on an existing item

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I've got a custom model inherited from  QTreeView.  I've enabled drag and drop and can currently drop an item onto the tree.  However, you can currently drop onto either an existing item or between items.  I would like to restrict this so that you can only drop onto existing items.

I've set DragDropOverwriteMode to true (actually this is the default for QTreeView).  However, this doesn't stop you from dropping between items - it just means you can also drop onto existing items.

I know that I can ignore the "insert" drops in dropMimeData (which I am reimplementing), by checking whether row and column are valid (drops onto existing items have row and column set to -1 and parent set to the current item) and I am doing this.  However, I would prefer not to get these drops.  Ie. I would like it so that you are always dropping over either the item above or the item below, never between items.

Any ideas?

Thanks for any advice,
Giles

Comment: Answer found now.  See comment on Matt's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'' need to catch the drag enter events by reimplementing the `dragEnterEvent` method in your custom view. The example from the Qt docs is:

```
void Window::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("text/plain"))
        event->acceptProposedAction();
}
```

In your case, you would probably need to compare the x and y position in the event with the x and y position of the closest item or something similar and reject or accept the proposed action based on that information.

From the `QAbstractItemModel::dropMimeData` documentation:

> It is the responsibility of the view to provide a suitable location for where the data should be inserted.

Which I have interpreted to mean that the view should reject the drop if it's not something that's supported by an underlying model, such as yours.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the useful info.  dragEnterEvent is not suitable as it is only called when you first drag over a widget, not repeatedly as the mouse moves over the widget.  However, the dragMoveEvent method does get called repeatedly so I think I can use that.

Comment: It does seem overly complicated to have to compare the rect of the moveEvent with the rect of all items in the tree.  Is there an easier way to determine if I am over an item rather than in between items?  I have looked at dropIndicatorPosition which sounds like it should do the right thing.  However that always returns 0 whether I am over an item or between items.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I've found a much easier way now which does exactly what I want.  Reimplement the flags method of the underlying model to return Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled only if passed index is valid.  When in between items, flags() is called with an invalid index so I can decide not to accept the drop.

Comment: Glad you found it. Now I learned something for my own implementations of models and views. :)

Comment: For the inverse you can do this:

            if ( index.isValid() )
            {
                return Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled;
            }
            else
            {
                return Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
            }

This helped me a lot :)!

Answer (score 3):

As of Qt 5.4 (and I assume this was true even in Qt 4.8), setting `DragDropOverwriteMode` to `true` will **correctly** cause the drags to be droppable only on existing items and prevents the "above/below items" drop targets from appearing.

Also, unlike what the question claims, `DragDropOverwriteMode` is set to `false` by default for `QTreeView` (I didn't check, maybe it's newer Qt versions), so it needs to be set to `true` manually.

However it is still useful to be able to calculate on what positions the item can be dropped. For example in QTreeView, one cannot drop a dragged thing on the left margin of the items, i.e the red area below:

[image: QTreeView invalid drop areas]

If something is dropped in the invalid red area, `dropMimeData` will be called with a `parent` argument set to `NULL`. So it would be useful to `ignore` the `dragMoveEvent` in advance to **show a 'you can't drop here' cursor to the user** so they know they can't drop there. Qt doesn't implement changing the mouse cursor on invalid areas while dragging (as of Qt 5.4), but we can do it like this:

```
bool SubclassedTreeView::dropResultsInValidIndex(const QPoint& pos)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem* item = itemAt(pos);
    if (item == NULL || !indexFromItem(item).isValid())
        return false;
    return visualRect(indexFromItem(item)).adjusted(-1, -1, 1, 1).contains(pos, false);
}

virtual void SubclassedTreeView::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent* event)
{
    QTreeWidget::dragMoveEvent(event);
    if (!event->isAccepted())
        return;

    if (dropResultsInValidIndex(event->pos()))
        event->accept();
    else
        event->ignore(); //Show 'forbidden' cursor.
}

virtual bool SubclassedTreeView::dropMimeData(QTreeWidgetItem* parent, int index, const QMimeData* data, Qt::DropAction action)
{
    Q_UNUSED(index);
    //Modify the following action and data format checks to suit your needs:
    if (parent == NULL || action != Qt::CopyAction || !data->hasFormat("my/preferred-type"))
        return false;

    QModelIndex modelIndex = indexFromItem(parent);
    //modelIndex is where the data is dropped onto. Implement your custom drop action here...

    return true;
}
```

The above code contains a little part `visualRect….adjusted(-1, -1, 1, 1)` which was stolen from `QAbstractItemViewPrivate::position` sources. Actually the sources of this function can be used to calculate the overwrite/insert/invalid areas for the item when `QAbstractItemViewPrivate::position` is `false` too.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a solution based on the current position of the drop indicator (`QAbstractItemView::DropIndicatorPosition`). It's pretty simple to implement, but unfortunately requires the drop indicator to be shown. However, this might be acceptable in some cases.

```
TreeView::TreeView(QWidget* parent) : QTreeView(parent)
{
    setDropIndicatorShown(true);
}

void TreeView::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent* event)
{
    QTreeView::dragMoveEvent(event);

    if (dropIndicatorPosition() != QTreeView::OnItem)
        event->setDropAction(Qt::IgnoreAction);
}
```